# update Ionic 2 with Angular Final 2.0 package?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am very much new to Ionic Framework. I want to develop an sample applciation using Ionic 2. Installing ionic 2 via npm is giving me **rc** versions of angular 2 i want to update with final version of it.

Can anyone help me out to get started with it...

Thanks

Comment: Which npm command you ran?

Comment: You have to wait the next release. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md Current version supports only angular2 rc.4

Comment: yes i got the same version rc.4